# What part-time opportunities are available for low hours pilots?

Tags: ppl, career, caa-uk-regulations

I hold an NPPL and have a career that I very much love and wouldn't want to change. However, I would also like to make some money from flying.

***What, if any, part time opportunities are available for someone with under 200 hours?*** Would anyone hire such a pilot for crop dusting, private transport, cargo or other jobs and only need someone recreationally?

I understand this might be far fetched and would also potentially involve upgrading to a PPL and getting instrument and/or commercial ratings added too.

Additional sub-question. If there are opportunities available, how does one find them?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/65917/what-steps-do-i-need-to-follow-to-use-my-ppl-for-income

Comment: Is the UK NPPL similar to the US sport pilot certificate or recreational pilot certificate?

Answer (score 13):

With an NPPL, you have no option to earn money from flying.

Upgrading to a PPL would allow you very limited opportunity to earn money.

The first step is possibly a [Class Rating Instructor](https://www.caa.co.uk/Commercial-industry/Pilot-licences/Instructors-and-Examiners/Class-Rating-Examiner/) which allows you to do things like club checkouts, revalidations etc.

Beyond that you could go for a fully fledged [Flight instructor](https://www.caa.co.uk/commercial-industry/pilot-licences/instructors-and-examiners/flight-examiner/) rating which would allow you to teach up to the NPPL but not the full PPL.

To teach PPL, you need the FI rating and at least the CPL exams, but almost everyone will advise you to go full CPL as the difference between CPL exams only and full CPL is just a few hours instruction and some flight time.

The best place to ask about such opportunities would be your local (or not so local) flight school. Check out the schools at your local airfield.

You can also tow gliders with a PPL, it wont pay you cash money, but it will pay you in flight hours. Its almost exclusively done by pilots with glider experience, so if you want to do that get going with your local gliding club.

Almost every other paying flying position will need a CPL at least.

Comment: Maybe worth noting that this isn't a "nobody will hire you" thing. Even if somebody would, e.g. pay you to fly some package over to their friend, you're legally barred from "commercial operations" without a CPL.

Comment: To add the above comment, I obtained a CPL-H in early 2001. The road to employment is long and difficult even as a CPL holder. It's possible if you are willing to relocate large distances, and probably remain unattached (so that you can relocate as needed, when needed). My perspective is from Canada. I never made use of my licence.